# Knotted Traveling Salesperson route

Tags: knot-theory, combinatorial-optimization, traveling-salesman-problem

Let us consider fixed points in space, if we apply the well-known Traveling Salesperson Problem algorithm, we get the shortest route. It can give a nontrivial knot in the three-space. The question is what is the minimum number of points that can be like this, i.e. "TSP non-trivial"?

I have found $16$ points, but don't know if we can get less.

[image]

The coordinates for the example are:

```
[[-2.35172872,  0.87499447, -0.86062952],
   [-1.27279499, -0.58250424, -0.79981732],
   [-0.35964634, -0.96662397,  0.24847584],
   [ 0.77356703, -1.69027479,  0.9899925 ],
   [ 2.68106959, -0.99753048,  0.50923161],
   [ 2.54586669,  1.16513512, -0.60024349],
   [ 0.61077421,  1.64158209, -0.96863809],
   [-0.42031143,  0.91839722, -0.14112001],
   [-1.39719379,  0.51984603,  0.86062952],
   [-2.36439472, -1.0820831 ,  0.79981732],
   [-1.03519417, -2.78229854, -0.24847584],
   [ 0.89102032, -1.94691491, -0.9899925 ],
   [ 1.06785291, -0.39731003, -0.50923161],
   [ 1.09132302,  0.49945222,  0.60024349],
   [ 0.78406629,  2.10734042,  0.96863809],
   [-1.24427592,  2.71879248,  0.14112001]]
```